# Updating matplotlib barchart

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am new to matplotlib, and trying to make a barchart from data in a MySQL database. The barchart is working fine, but when new records are added to the database while the program is running, the barchart is not updating. In order to show the new values in the barchart, the program needs to be closed and opened again. This is the code for the function i made which executes each time a button is pressed in a tkinter gui, and i know that this is probably not the best way to solve this. I want the barchart to update when the button is pressed. Any tips on this?

```
def graphs(self):
    self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Enrollment; ')
    result = self.cursor.fetchall()

    economics = 0
    information_science = 0
    data_science = 0
    mathematics = 0
    politics = 0
    history = 0
    information_sec = 0
    music = 0
    medicine = 0
    business = 0

    for row in result:
        if row[2] == 1:
            economics += 1
        elif row[2] == 2:
            information_science += 1
        elif row[2] == 3:
            data_science += 1
        elif row[2] == 4:
            mathematics += 1
        elif row[2] == 5:
            politics += 1
        elif row[2] == 6:
            history += 1
        elif row[2] == 7:
            information_sec += 1
        elif row[2] == 8:
            music += 1
        elif row[2] == 9:
            medicine += 1
        elif row[2] == 10:
            business += 1

    values = [economics, information_science, data_science, mathematics, politics,
              history, information_sec, music, medicine, business]
    keys = ['Economics', 'Information Science', 'Data Science', 'Mathematics', 'Politics',
            'History', 'Information Security', 'Music Studies', 'Medicine', 'Business Analytics']
    plt.bar(keys, values, zorder=3)
    plt.title('Students in each course')
    plt.xlabel('Courses')
    plt.ylabel('Students')
    plt.xticks(keys, rotation='vertical')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
    plt.grid(zorder=0)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You could simplify the large for expression by using a dictionary instead of individual variables. Then the code inside your for block would be something like `if row[2] in your_dict`, `dict[row[2]] += 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem. Counting the values using SQL also simplified my code tremendously.

```
def graphs(self):
    self.cursor.execute('SELECT Course_ID, Count(*) FROM Enrollment GROUP BY Course_ID; ')
    result = self.cursor.fetchall()

    df = DataFrame(result)
    keys = ['Economics', 'Information Science', 'Data Science', 'Mathematics', 'Politics',
            'History', 'Information Security', 'Music Studies', 'Medicine', 'Business Analytics']
    values = df[1]
    plt.bar(keys, values, zorder=3)
    plt.title('Students in each course')
    plt.xlabel('Courses')
    plt.ylabel('Students')
    plt.xticks(keys, rotation='vertical')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
    plt.grid(zorder=0)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can save multiple images without having to close the program:

```
count = 0

    plt.savefig('bar'+str(count)+'.png')
    count += 1
```